# How can i set and access config variables in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make some environment variables. How can i set/get them? For example, i want to add the variable virtual_host and be able to access it from everywhere in my application.

Thank you

Comment: [close] - This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form - and may lead to extended discussion :)

Answer (score 2):

For config variables in a Rails application, I tend to use [ActiveSupport::Configurable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Configurable.html). This works really well if your variables are related to a specific class. Say you have a class called Security, and you want to configure global properties for this class.

```
class Security
  include ActiveSupport::Configurable

  config.enabled = true
  config.level = 'high'

  config_accessor :enabled, :level
end
```

If you want to share this class between lots of applications, you can set the config variables at runtime in an initializer:

```
Security.config.enabled = false
```

Since I've declared both variables via config_accessor, you don't have to prefix them with `config`. You can simply call Security.enabled or Security.level. This is optional though.

One of the other nice things about this method is that the configs are inherited by subclasses, but can be overridden:

```
class LessSecurity < Security
  config.level = 'medium'
end
```

Comment: I tend to just add my own config variables to the Rails configuration itself, but I didn't know about `ActiveSupport::Configurable`, thanks.

Comment: PS: One benefit to adding them to the Rails config is that you can easily have different configurations between the different environments.

Comment: And reading them from a YAML file or something wouldn't be too difficult with this method either.

Answer (score 0):

Define a Helper class to have access to these properties and you can access it anywhere you need. Also it has the added benefi of centralizing your "globals" while giving you the opportunity to put business logic around then.

See here for an example: http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/site-wide-global-variables-in-ruby-on-rails/

EDIT:

Regarding setting these values to persist later, you can create an ApplicationConfig Model object. Just understand how this confit will work: is it linked to a user preference or to the application as a whole, and the overhead involved in persisting and retrieving these values.